# AWS CLI not installing all the way

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pip, command-line-interface

Trying to get a nodeJS app up on AWS, but when installing the Command Line Interface(CLI) with the command that aws it's telling me:  pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user
Unfortunately I get Requirement not upgraded as not directly required:

matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
python-dateutil 2.7.2 has requirement six>=1.5, but you'll have six 1.4.1 which is incompatible.
blessed 1.14.2 has requirement six>=1.9.0, but you'll have six 1.4.1 which is incompatible

I am not to familiar with Python, but I do have 2.7.2 on my system and installed pip as well. Not sure what to do? I am guessing a command to get nose and tornado and blessed installed?

Comment: I think the problem here is that the version of `pip` you are using is not installing `awscli` for your system's version of Python. There could be a variety of other other reasons. As a general rule of thumb, I recommend using [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv) to compartmentalize your Python executable and packages. It will take you 5 minutes at most to get set up and you will never run into the problem again.

Comment: It was the version of pip after all!  Looking into using virtualenv..